# Angular: Can i have a private service scoped to its module?

Tags: angular

In an angular 5 application, I have a module responsible for dispensing a specific piece of data. This service injects two services -- one retrieves data from `localStorage`, if found, and another that requests the same data from the server if not found. I want this module to expose the retrieved data without exposing the services that actually do the retrieval, but i am having problems.

**DataService:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService,
              private storageService: LocalStorageService) { }

  get = (): Observable<User> => {
    const data: string = this.storageService.fetch();
    if (data) {
      return Observable.of(JSON.parse(data));
    }
    return this.httpService
      .get();
  };
}
```

**HttpService:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  private dataUrl = 'api/endpoint';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private storageService: LocalStorageService) {}
  get = () => {
    return this.http
      .get(this.dataUrl)
      .map((retrieved: any) => {
        this.storageService.store(retrieved);
        return retrieved;
      }).catch(() => Observable.throw(err));
  };
}
```

**LocalStorageService:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

  private key = 'dataKey';

  constructor() { }

  fetch = (): string => {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.key); 
  };

  store(d: any): void  {
    localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(d));
  };
}
```

I tried defining the module by exposing only `DataService`:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DataService
  ]
})
export class DataModule {}
```

The result was `StaticInjectorError[HttpService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpService!"` and a similar error for `LocalStorageService`, both thrown by `app.module`.

I can get the app working by redefining the `NgModule` providers declaration to include the injected services that should remain private:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DataService,
    LocalStorageService,
    HttpService
  ]
})
export class DataModule {}
```

However, this exposes those services to any module importing `DataModule`, which is specifically what i want to avoid. Is there a way to make an `@Injectable` available for dependency injection within a module without adding it to `providers` and exposing it outside the module?

Comment: At the end of the day, if someone imports your service they can use it in their module.

Comment: I think the way you have it as `providers: [
    DataService,
    LocalStorageService,
    HttpService
  ]` makes sense. The `DataModule` declared what it needs, but anyone using `DataModule` doesn't declare those things again. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Sure. But it seems that i have to let everyone who imports my service also have transitive access to its dependencies?

Comment: @TheHeadRush: I don't know of any dependency injection framework that supports what you need. You're better off stripping out the `@Injectable` from the classes, if privacy is that important for you. Otherwise, follow the happy path, and do what Mr. Angular tells you to do...!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expose through `Module` then you can provide `HttpService` at component level. Note, providing the services at component will create new instance for each component wherever you provide it.

Syntax for providing is same as for Module

```
 providers: [
    DataService,
    LocalStorageService,
    HttpService
  ]
```

Comment: `DataService` provides a resource that needs to be used by components in other modules of the application. But unless i expose it in providers, it cannot be accessed by these components. But it seems that i cannot expose `DataService` without also exposing the supporting `@Injectables`.